# Implementing abstract methods in a subclass in Java

Tags: java, abstract-class

I've made my code as generic as possible to try and help people in the future. My abstract class has a method of the type class and and an input of the type class. In the class that extends the abstract, I try to implement that method to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

```
public abstract class A {
    public abstract A method1(A arg);
}

public class B extends A {
    @Override
    public B method1(B arg) { "...insert code here"} // Error: The method method1(B) must override or implement a supertype method
}
```

Comment: The arg has to be of type `A`.

Comment: Does the argument of the method have to be of the same exact type as the subclass (in your example `B`)?

Comment: Yes. There are methods only in B that I need in B.method1.

Comment: @MasterBob You can always send the reference of B while calling. What I mean is `B.method1(new B());`. This is possible as the reference of A can point to implementation class but that would require you to have the method declaration in abstract class. As the reference of A can only point to  methods whose declaration is present in it's body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve what you want : associating the type of the argument to the declared class, you could use generics.

abstract class :

```
public abstract class A <T extends A<T>> {
    public abstract T method1(T arg);
}
```

concrete class :

```
public class B extends A<B> {
    @Override
    public B method1(B arg) { 
     ...
      return ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This generates warnings, since `A` is generic and in `<T extends A>` `A` isn't. You should fix it as follows: `<T extends A<T>>`

Answer (score 3):

Think about the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle): in order to be indistinguishable from a superclass, the subclass must accept all of the same parameters that the superclass would; and return something that the superclass *might*.

Another way to put this is that the subclass method can:

- Return a more specific type that the superclass method (since this is a value that the superclass might return); for example, if the superclass returns `Object`, the subclass can return a `String`, because all `String`s are `Object`s.

  This is called a *covariant return type*, and is permitted in Java. Subclasses can not only return more specific return types, they can also throw more specific checked exceptions than the superclass; but they can also *not* declare that they throw the checked exceptions thrown by the superclass method.
- Accept a more general type than the superclass method (since this allows the subclass to accept all parameters that the superclass would).

  This would be called a *contravariant parameter type*; but it is *not* permitted in Java. The reason is to do with the way that overloads are selected in Java: unfortunately, the method signatures (which includes the parameter types, but not the return type) have to be *identical*.

The relevant section of the language spec is [JLS Sec 8.4.8.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3).

Your problem is making the parameter type `B`: this is *more* specific than `A`, so an instance of `B` is not substitutable for an instance of `A`, because `A.method1` accepts a parameter `A`, whereas `B.method1` does not.

Make `B.method1` take a parameter of type `A`.

Answer (score 2):

The type and no of parameter should remain. The return type, if it is of primitive type, should remain same, but if it is of reference type then it can be of subclass type.

In your case change this `public B method1(B arg) { "...insert code here"}` to `public B method1(A arg) { "...insert code here"}`

Answer (score 1):

Every thing you have written is right except overidden method argument type,you can't change the signature of superclass abstract method while overiding in subclass.

```
public abstract class A {
    public abstract A method1(A arg);
}

public class B extends A {
    @Override
    public B method1(A arg) { "...insert code here"} // Error: The method method1(B) must override or implement a supertype method
}
```

Comment: Sorry for mistake @AndyTurner i wrote return type instead of argument type. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

The contract of `A.method1` means that every object that is an `A` must have a `method1` which can take any `A` object.

In the case of `B.method1`, it can take a `B` object, but it cannot take another `A`.